# What is an easy way for users to remotely change their passwords on mac os x snow leopard servers?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, passwords, ftp, osx-server

I have been entrusted with our little snow leopard server. It is supposed to work as an FTP server - and does (hooray). Now, I have given the six or so people in our team usernames and passwords to login to the server via FTP, but I want them to able to change their passwords after their first login.

I tried to follow the steps I found [on this site](http://support.cdh.ucla.edu/help/132-file-transfer-protocol-ftp/478-changing-ftp-account-password-windows), but they are not working.

The error I get just says `?Invalid command.`

If there is another way or anybody knows what could be wrong, I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

To change your password using the instructions you linked, your FTP server would need to support the change password command. You don't mention the FTP service used (I imagine it's the built in OS X FTP service) but it sounds like changing the password via FTP commands is not supported.

You could have your users telnet in and change their password there instead. Do note that both telnet and FTP passwords are sent in the clear, and it might not hurt to change to SSH and SFTP.

Answer (score 0):

Snow Leopard Server's web service has a password change service available. It's enabled in Server Admin -> Web service in the sidebar -> Sites -> select/create an SSL-protected virtual site -> Web Services subtab -> "Allow users to change their password" checkbox. Note that this is only available with SSL sites (to protect the passwords being sent to the server), so you'll need an SSL certificate -- either a proper signed cert (which costs money), or the auto-created self-signed cert (which will give your users an untrusted cert warning, and you should *not* be teaching your users to click OK/Continue/etc on such warnings). So, it's not optimal; sorry...